# jQuery GET not sending IE in browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, post, get

I have the following lump of code in a project I am working on:

```
if(!validate($(".emailbody input").val())){
    ...
}
else{
    $.get("https://get.request.com/something", {email:encodeURI($(".emailbody input").val())})
    .complete(function(){
        $(".emailbody").append($('<p class="emailsucess">Kiitos! Linkki rekisteröitymisen jatkamiseen on lähetetty sähköpostiisi: '+$(".emailbody input").val()+'</p>'));
        $.post("http://post.request/confirm.php", {"confirm":$(".emailbody input").val()})
        $(".emailbody input").val("");
    });
}
```

A simple get requst puts things into the database of a connected service, and then a post response fires off a mail from the local host.

**My problem is this:**

In every other browser other than IE (any version) this works quite happily and without any problem whatsoever, however with IE the GET call doesn't even appear on the network traffic, it is ignored, not called, but the complete call is still made as if it went through OK!

Is this a problem with the https service, or is there something that that i've missed?

**UPDATE:**
Ive got around the problem by making a post call to a local file which pings on the GET request to the external server, so that is now working, but its a stupid way of doing things. Anyone who can shed some light onto this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding a random value variable at the end, or a timestamp. IE has a nasty habit of caching the requests.

Comment: doesnt seem to help, even when changing the address that is sent/adding timestamp variables it still doesnt seem to try and send.

Comment: `https://get.request.com` is the same domain as the page is on? The sending page also is on https already?

Answer (score 6):

Seems like a caching issue. GET requests could be cached so you could try appending a random querystring parameter to the url to avoid this. Or use `$.ajax` with `cache: false`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://get.request.com/something',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { email: $(".emailbody input").val() } // <-- note that you don't need to encode here, jQuery will take care of this
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Also make sure that you respect the [same origin policy restriction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). The best way to ensure this is to use relative urls. So instead of:

```
'https://get.request.com/something'
```

use:

```
'/something'
```

Comment: it isnt possible to use the same origin policy, due to the fact im trying to get a response from a https service when im in an http, so relitive values dont work. I dont think that it is a caching problem because it doesnt load the request even when you do it the first time around, not just in subsiquent attempts, so it doesnt have a chance to cache. Any other ideas?